# apache-flink +spring boot - logs related to spring boot application start up not printed in file in flink 1.12

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, apache-flink

I was getting bean creation logs and spring boot start up logs in Flink 1.9
with flink1.9_log4j-cli.properties (attached)

```
    ################################################################################
#  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
#  or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
#  distributed with this work for additional information
#  regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
#  to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
#  "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
#  with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
#  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
################################################################################

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file


# Log all infos in the given file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.file=${log.file}
log4j.appender.file.append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n


# Log output from org.apache.flink.yarn to the console. This is used by the
# CliFrontend class when using a per-job YARN cluster.
log4j.logger.org.apache.flink.yarn=INFO, console
log4j.logger.org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli=INFO, console
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop=INFO, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n

# suppress the warning that hadoop native libraries are not loaded (irrelevant for the client)
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader=OFF

# suppress the irrelevant (wrong) warnings from the netty channel handler
log4j.logger.org.apache.flink.shaded.akka.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline=ERROR
```

but after updating to Flink 1.12.1 those logs are not getting printed in log file
attaching flink1.12_log4j-cli.properties

```
    ################################################################################
#  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
#  or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
#  distributed with this work for additional information
#  regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
#  to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
#  "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
#  with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
#  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
################################################################################

rootLogger.level = INFO
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref = FileAppender

# Log all infos in the given file
appender.file.name = FileAppender
appender.file.type = FILE
appender.file.append = true
appender.file.fileName = ${sys:log.file}
appender.file.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n

logger.flink.name = org.apache.flink
logger.flink.level = INFO

# Log output from org.apache.flink.yarn to the console. This is used by the
# CliFrontend class when using a per-job YARN cluster.
logger.yarn.name = org.apache.flink.yarn
logger.yarn.level = INFO
logger.yarn.appenderRef.console.ref = ConsoleAppender
logger.yarncli.name = org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli
logger.yarncli.level = INFO
logger.yarncli.appenderRef.console.ref = ConsoleAppender
logger.hadoop.name = org.apache.hadoop
logger.hadoop.level = INFO
logger.hadoop.appenderRef.console.ref = ConsoleAppender

# Log output from org.apache.flink.kubernetes to the console.
logger.kubernetes.name = org.apache.flink.kubernetes
logger.kubernetes.level = INFO
logger.kubernetes.appenderRef.console.ref = ConsoleAppender

appender.console.name = ConsoleAppender
appender.console.type = CONSOLE
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n

# suppress the warning that hadoop native libraries are not loaded (irrelevant for the client)
logger.hadoopnative.name = org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader
logger.hadoopnative.level = OFF

# Suppress the irrelevant (wrong) warnings from the Netty channel handler
logger.netty.name = org.apache.flink.shaded.akka.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline
logger.netty.level = ERROR
```

I am not able to get this log in file
is there some setting changes needed to be done to enable this?
What is required to get similar logging?